# How to connect datasource with JBoss AS7

Tags: jboss7.x

I am new to Jboss Application Server 7. I am trying to create a datasource. I have added the following code in the standalone.xml:

```
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/sss" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="sss">
            <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:sid</connection-url>
            <driver> ojdbc14.jar</driver>
            <pool></pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>username</user-name>
                <password>password</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="ojdbc14.jar" module="com.oracle">
                <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
```

I have placed my ojdbc14.jar in the following path, `\jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final\modules\com\oracle\main`.

I have persisted module.xml, as follows in the same path.

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc14.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
         <module name="javax.api"/>
         <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

But I get the error as follows,

> ERROR [stderr] Exception in thread "Controller Boot Thread" java.la
>   ng.RuntimeException: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenc
>   eException: Failed to parse configuration

Can any one please help me in solving this error?.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something is wrong with your configuration. My guess would be the pool configuration. Can you try something like this:

```
<pool>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
</pool>
```

And just to be sure remove the space in

```
<driver> ojdbc14.jar</driver>
```

Some other points. You probably want to use the Oracle validation classes.

```
<validation>
    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
    <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
</validation>
```

In addition you probably want to use the Oracle driver that matches your JRE/JDK. Since you're likely not on Java 1.4 you shouldn't use ojdbc14.jar. If you're on Java 1.5 you should use ojdbc5.jar and if you're on Java 1.6 you should use ojdbc6.jar.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to deploy DS: either as a module or as a deployment. Have a look at [this article](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7) for more details.
Besides, for some reason JBoss config parser is somehow sensitive to errors in any config files, review your config once again, looking for any misspelled words or unnecessary white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by the config file that you've read or are aware of the community documentation.

Link: [JBoss Application Server 7 - Datasources documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Datasources)

Have you tried the datasource deployment method, deploying your driver with the Management Console or the CLI? Also curious what the CLI reports on a `read-resource` operation on the datasource node.

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] /subsystem=datasources:read-resource(recursive=true)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that there is a compatibility problem.

- JBoss AS7 run under java 6 and only works with jdbc driver versions 4.0.
- The jdbc driver ojdbc14.jar is compiled with java 1.4 and it is jdbc 3.0 or lower.

Maybe it can't work together.

I would try with the jdbc drivers for oracle11g (for backward compatibility). I've found this [Interoperability Matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/index-099369.html) for the JDBC drivers

Comment: Not sure what you want to say. Be specific and write full words.

Comment: @SantoshJoshi Sorry, I've tried to explain it better. Thanks for the advice.